# How to generate a Bootstrap Popover when selecting text across multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

How can I generate a Bootstrap popover at a mouseevent (like `mouseup` or `click`) when a user selects text across more than one `<div>`?

I tried to create a copy of my HTML and JQuery (as close as I could) in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinit144/hq1zgswf/9/).

As you can see in the fiddle's example, I cannot use a `div` that encapsulates all text `<div>`s because each one has an id that I need for the functioning of the buttons that the popover will have.

You will notice that a popover appears when text is selected in a single `div`, but when you select text from more than 1 `div`, the popover does not appear.

Funny thing is that this worked on Firefox a week or so ago, but stopped working as soon as I updated Firefox to the latest version (`66.0.2`).
To add, this issue has been there on chrome since the start.

I have tried different solutions that I found here on Stack Overflow but none of them seemed to work in my case.

Any solutions as to what I am doing wrong, what alternative ways I could try to do this, or reasons as to why this may not work?

Edit:

I have tried `mouseup` for this as well and it doesn't seem to work in this version of FF or the latest Chrome. I changed it to `click` because I also have other popovers which close when the user `clicks` in the `main_div` or anywhere outside the popovers. 
Since the `click` event occurs after the `mouseup` event, I found that it would kill my popover instantly after it appeared. I had to remove this popover from the list of popovers that were click in the aforementioned `click` event and manually added it for places where I wanted it to happen.

I have no issues with using `mouseup`, just that I tried it and I didn't observe any benefits over `click` so I changed it temporarily.

Comment: changing the click event to `mousedown` seems to do what you intend. Give that a try, or let me know if I've misinterpreted anything.

Comment: @CristianC. Hey, thanks for responding. I need to generate the popover near the mouse pointer's final location as the user may select several divs (i.e., rows of text) at a time. I think `mousedown` won't work for that purpose. P.S: Thanks for the edit suggestion, I made the changes.

Comment: you could do the same thing with `mouseup`, in that case you'll know the cursor's last position.

Comment: @CristianC. I was using the `mouseup` event before I changed it to `click` in my project to check if this would work. In [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinit144/hq1zgswf/17/) as well it doesn't work for me whether I use `mouseup` or `click`. Could this be a localized issue due to some extension? It also happens on chrome though which I use exclusively for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your .on("click"...) to .on("mouseup"...).

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, x64. 
Firefox 66.0.2

```js
$("#main_div").on("mouseup", ".messagebox", function(e) {
  var selected_text = window.getSelection().toString();
  var elem = $(this);
  var row = elem.closest(".message_row");
  var id = $(row).attr("data-msg-id")
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (selected_text !== "") {
    elem.popover({
      placement: "top",
      content: ("ID:" + id + " Text: " + selected_text),
      trigger: "manual",
    });
    elem.popover("show");
  }
});

// Remove Popover on Hover
$("body").on('mouseenter', '.popover', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
#main_div {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.messagebox {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="main_div">
    <div class="big_box">
      <div class="message_row" data-msg-id="50">
        <div class="messagebox">
          <div class="message_content">
            <p>
              Random Text Here.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="message_row" data-msg-id="51">
        <div class="messagebox">
          <div class="message_content">
            <p>
              Some Text here
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="message_row" data-msg-id="52">
        <div class="messagebox">
          <div class="message_content">
            <p>
              Some more text here.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, this is pretty weird. When I run this snippet here, it works when selecting multiple divs. But when I try it in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinit144/hq1zgswf/17/) it isn't working. Also, I was using the `mouseup` event before I changed it to `click` in my project like I mentioned at the start in my question (I see it wasn't very clear so I'll add some context). fwiw, I am on Windows 10, same browser.

Comment: Tested it on Windows Server 2019 x64,1809. Same FF version, Works!

Comment: I might be able to add some context. Because your `mouseup` is only triggered when it happens within the `.messagebox` elements, if you select text but then before releasing you go outside of the element, it wont trigger the event. This might be why youre seeing it not work, but it does, indeed, work as intended.

Comment: @Marc I'll test this out on my project and see if it works. Thanks for quick responses!

Comment: @CristianC. Yeah I tried to stay within the `messagebox` element when releasing the mouse. I am not sure what is happening on my system here. This is a weird behavior.

Comment: Update: This worked. I had another conflicting event handler that was messing it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to achieve individual tooltips for each messagebox. This allow each message box to have it's own set of `elem`, `text`, `row`, and `id` variables.

```
$('.messagebox').each(function() {
    var elem = $(this),
        text = elem.find('.message_content p').text(),
        row = elem.closest('.message_row'),
        id = row.attr('data-msg-id');

    elem.on('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        var args = {
            placement: "top",
            content: ("ID:" + id + " Text: " + text),
            trigger: "manual",
        };

        elem.popover(args);
        elem.popover("show");
    });
});
```